# Cannot download html table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to download html table using this script but it's not working for all users. Do you have some suggestions why it's happening? The table results or query from sql opening up in a new window and from their I have "download" link that the script below need to pass to excel.

```
function fnExcelReport() {
    var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<meta charset="UTF-8">';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<head><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Tickets</x:Name>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
    tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';
    tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='1px'>";
    tab_text = tab_text + $('#dvData').html();
    tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';

    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
        if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            var blob = new Blob([tab_text], {
                type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
            });
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'Test file.xls');
        }
    } else {
        $('#test').attr('href', data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
        $('#test').attr('download','open', 'Test file.xls');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#test').attr('href', data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
$('#test').attr('target', '_blank');
$('#test').attr('download','open', 'Test file.xls');
```